# Empilhando e desempilhando com fila no javascript

Tags: javascript, fila

Eu tenho que empilhar 3 valores que forem digitados pelo usuário através do prompt, e depois disto desempilhar, mostrando o resultado na tela.

O problema é que após o usuário digitar os 3 valores, ele aparece a seguinte palavra 3 vezes, ao invés dos valores :

> undefined

Como eu posso arrumar este erro e empilhar e desempilhar corretamente ? Desde já agradeço pelas respostas.

**Meu código :**

```
<html>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript"/>

function FIFO(){
    this.fila = new Array();
this.Enfileira = function(obj){
    this.fila[this.fila.length] = obj;
}

this.Desenfileira = function(){
if (this.fila.length > 0){
    var obj = this.fila[0];
    this.fila.splice(0,1);
    return obj;
}else{
    alert ("Não há objetos na fila.")
}
}
}
</script>
</head>

<body>

<h1>EXEMPLO FILA</h1>
<script type="text/javascript"/>

var minhafila = new FIFO();

minhafila.Enfileira = prompt ("Digite um texto : ");
minhafila.Enfileira = prompt ("Digite um texto : ");
minhafila.Enfileira = prompt ("Digite um texto : ");

var desenf1 = minhafila.Desenfileira();
document.write(desenf1,"</br>");
var desenf2 = minhafila.Desenfileira();
document.write(desenf2,"</br>");
var desenf3 = minhafila.Desenfileira();
document.write(desenf3,"</br>");
</script>


</body>


</html>
```

Comment: O que você acha que `minhafila.Enfileira = prompt ("Digite um texto : ");` faz?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parece que seu texto também tem problemas, empilhar é de [PILHA](http://www.dca.fee.unicamp.br/cursos/EA876/apostila/HTML/node30.html), e enfileirar é de [FILA](http://www.dca.fee.unicamp.br/cursos/EA876/apostila/HTML/node30.html), tem um significado no mundo da informática diferente, onde [PILHA](http://www.dca.fee.unicamp.br/cursos/EA876/apostila/HTML/node30.html) *o primeiro que entra é o último que sai, porque a remoção do itens é sempre do topo* e [FILA](http://www.dca.fee.unicamp.br/cursos/EA876/apostila/HTML/node30.html) *o primeiro que entra é o primeiro que sai*, mas, vamos para o código que aparentemente estava correto, mas, no momento que foi setar os número fez o código errado onde:

```
minhafila.Enfileira = prompt ("Digite um texto : "); // errado
```

dever ser isso:

```
minhafila.Enfileira(prompt ("Digite um texto : ")); // correto
```

porque o seu `Enfileira` é um `método` que recebe um valor, diferente de uma propriedade que pode ser atribuído como foi feito na pergunta.

***Exemplo minimo:***

```js
function FIFO() {
  this.fila = new Array();
  this.Enfileira = function(obj) {
    this.fila[this.fila.length] = obj;
  }
  this.Desenfileira = function() {
    if (this.fila.length > 0) {
      var obj = this.fila[0];
      this.fila.splice(0, 1);
      return obj;
    } else {
      alert("Não há objetos na fila.")
    }
  }
}

var minhafila = new FIFO(); 

minhafila.Enfileira(prompt ("Digite um texto : "));
minhafila.Enfileira(prompt ("Digite um texto : "));
minhafila.Enfileira(prompt ("Digite um texto : "));

var desenf1 = minhafila.Desenfileira();
document.write(desenf1,"</br>"); 
var desenf2 = minhafila.Desenfileira();
document.write(desenf2,"</br>"); 
var desenf3 = minhafila.Desenfileira();
document.write(desenf3,"</br>");
```

Comment: Obrigado, coloquei os termos empilhando e desempilhando de forma errada, e também sou novo ainda em javascript, por isto os erros simples. Enfim, muito obrigado, +1 e resposta certa.